# (QGIS 3.20) Adding features while spatial index is created makes them disappear

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-3, spatial-index

I am encountering a weird behaviour in QGIS 3.20 on Windows.

Steps to reproduce:

- Create an empty project
- Create a SHP layer.
- Add a few features.
- Save the changes to disk

At this point everything is fine. Features still appears.

- I create a spacial index for the layer
- Add a new feature
- Save changes to disk.
- Zoom out/in
- The latest features disapears.

This problem dosn't happen on my Linux machine, but happens on Windows.
I found out that on save, on my Linux box, the `.qix` file is deleted, whereas on Windows it is not. When deleting the `.qix` file on Windows, the features reappears. This seems the be a common issue dating back a few years.

How can I make the features stay or make the deletion of the `.qix` happen?

I found this [issue on the qgis tracker](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/42567), I know this is a QGIS bug, and I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: I've noticed feature disappearance can occur when the index files are the ArcGIS sbn and sbx when working in a mixed QGIS and ArcGIS setting.  QGIS can read those files but it can't write them.  I'll run the Check Geometry tool and everything draws.  Alternately I might use ArcCatalog to update the indexes after removing the layer (so QGIS doesn't lock it) and then adding the layer back in.